# Quelles sont les différences entre rhabiller ou réhabiller ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, mots-composés

Il existe deux mots français qui proviennent étymologiquement du verbe *habiller* avec le préfixe *ré*. Sont-ils des synonymes ? Sinon, quelles sont les différence entre eux ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ce sont indubitablement des synonymes.

La différence est essentiellement l'usage. ***[Rhabiller](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rhabiller)*** est le verbe documenté et utilisé couramment alors que ***réhabiller*** est une variante rare et peut être régionale, absente des dictionnaires de référence (on ne la [trouve](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9habiller) guère que dans le Wiktionnaire).

On peut comparer la paire ***rhabiller/réhabiller*** avec ***rouvrir*** (standard)/***réouvrir*** (« déviant » mais très courant à l'oral) mais la deuxième s'explique plus facilement par la présence du substantif ***réouverture*** alors que ***réhabillage*** n'a pas d'existence « officielle ».

A l'inverse, la forme ***[réhabituer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9habituer)***, initialement rare a fini par supplanter ***[rhabituer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rhabituer)*** au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. On trouve aussi ***réhabiliter*** qui semble avoir toujours primé sur ***rhabiliter***.

[image] Une raison expliquant l'utilisation de ***réhabiller*** est aussi sa symétrie avec ***déshabiller***.

Comment: ***Réhabiller*** (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9habiller) donne des exemples pertinents que j'ai souvent entendus.

Comment: Chez le médecin, vous êtes *déshabillé* : « — Vous pouvez vous *rhabiller* maintenant, mais pour tenir compte de votre problème, il faudra vous *réhabiller* plus chaudement. » — *R**é**habiller* Il y a vraiment la notion de remettre des vêtements à nouveau, une seconde fois, ou, d'enfiler d'autres vêtements avec une notion de rupture avec la situation actuelle (pour l'esthétique, le confort, …) ; cela vaut pour le corps humain comme pour tout objet susceptible d'avoir une "peau", une enveloppe autonome, une apparence modifiable … comme un changement *d'habillage*.

Comment: Il y a aussi la consonance avec ***réhabil**iter*

Comment: @Personne Oui, merci pour *réhabiliter*. En revanche, je ne suis pas convaincu qu'il y ait vraiment une différence de sens entre *rhabiller* et *réhabiller*.

Comment: Cela se comprend, car tous les lettrés suppriment le **é**, et l'évolution normative est à l'oubli des citations relevées par Wikipédia, mais elles avaient encore cours après-guerre. J'imagine que l'on me propose un projet d'architecture, d'instinct je dirais « Il pourrait être intéressant de ré-habiller cette façade dans un style plus épuré » parce que « allez vous/la rhabiller »  https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/aller-se-rhabiller serait un refus définitif. Peut-être une spécificité hexagonale dans la francophonie héritée du siècle passé ?

Answer (score 1):

Réhabiller ne figure pas dans le dictionnaire.

Cela dit le français est une langue vivante et le dictionnaire suit les usages. Vous pouvez donc bien sûr l’utiliser, et la recherche Google montre que vous ne serez pas le seul, mais il n’empêche que ce ne serait pas correct.

Comment: Avec quoi n'es-tu pas d'accord dans ma réponse ?

Comment: En rien j’ai lu trop vite, l’œil attiré par le graphique des résultats Google.